# Restricting column values in Pandas Pivot

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have some data with an index mapped to key-value pairs like so:

```
# create fake data
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
data = '''
ID Time Flag Value
0 1:10 Start 10
0 1:11 Category Animal
0 1:13 Type Cat
0 1:13 End 13
'''
df1 = pd.read_table(StringIO(data),sep='\s+')
```

If I use Pandas Pivot, I can convert all factors in the `Flag` column to separate columns:

```
df2 = df1.pivot(index = 'ID', columns = 'Flag', values = 'Value')
```

However, this gives me ALL keys mapped to separate columns like this:

```
Flag Category End Start Type
ID                          
0      Animal  13    10  Cat
```

My question is, how can I restrict the factors/classes in `Flag` column to say, only include `Category` and `Type`without having to manually drop columns? In other words:

```
Flag Category Type
ID                          
0    Animal   Cat
```

The reason I ask is because the dataset that I am working on has close to ~1000 key-value pairs, so manually dropping the reshaped column is definitely not an attractive option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter using [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) so that you only get the values you are interested in:

```
In [142]:

categories = ['Category', 'Type']
df2 = df1[df1['Flag'].isin(categories)].pivot(index = 'ID', columns = 'Flag', values = 'Value')
df2
Out[142]:
Flag Category Type
ID                
0      Animal  Cat
```